# Função nativa mail() do PHP retorna verdadeiro e não envia Email

Tags: php, email

Bom dia!

Estou com uma pedra em meu sapato que preciso de orientação. Por meio de um arquivo separado (que estou chamando de funcao_email.php) dentro da minha pasta "inclusao" na raiz, criei uma função (baseado na mail) PHP que envia emails quando chamados nas páginas PHP. O problema dessa bendita é que quando ela é chamada, ela retorna TRUE, mas, o email não chega no destinatário.

Ora bolas, no primeiro dia eu testei excessivamente com o Hotmail, e não chegava nem por reza brava. Então, decidi testar no GMAIL e funcionou. O email chegou tudo funcionando perfeitamente. Depois de três dias, fui testá-lo de novo por pensar que naquele dia o Hotmail estava em manutenção ou algo do tipo, e o resultado me surpreendeu. A função continua retornando True mas, nenhum dos provedores (ou qualquer um) recebe o email.

```
function sentRegister($usuario, $senha, $email) {
    $subject = "Bem-vindo(a) ao nosso site!";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: no-reply@forumeiros.com \r\n";

    $mensagem = '<p>EMAIL TESTE COM: '.$email.' e '.$senha.' mais o '.$usuario.'</p>';

    // START SENT MAIL FUNCTION
    mail($email, $subject, $mensagem, $headers);
}
```

Essa é a função PHP, e chamo ela normalmente usando o IF:

```
if($usuario_inserido) {sentRegister($usuario, $senha, $email);)
```

Óbvio que as variáveis $usuario, $senha e $email retornam os dados vindos do $_POST. E confirmo que estão retornando valores, pois, testei. :)

Alguém saberia me indicar o que posso estar errando?

Comment: Como é que você está testando o retorno numa função sem `return`? Outra coisa, o retorno da função `mail` significa que o email foi inserido na fila de saída com sucesso, e não necessariamente que percorreu o caminho todo até o destino. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php - Já adiantando: tem um pessoal com mania de criticar a função `mail` dizendo que "você tem que usar PHPMailer incondicionalmente etc", mas vale lembrar que o `mail` funciona muito bem para situações simples do cotidiano.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23616/57801

Comment: Em sistemas com base em `sendmail` o parâmetro `-f` pode fazer diferença significativa. Veja no link do manual acima a opção `additional_parameters` - De qualquer forma, se optar pelo PHPMailer, já tem solução nesta postagem: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40858/70 (já estou comentando antes que postem duplicatas sem uso do `mail()`)

Comment: Se optar por PHPMailer use a versão mais atualizada PHPMailer 6 que foi lançado no final de agosto de 2017 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252928/preenchendo-remetente-com-o-campo-de-email-php-mailer/253022#253022

Comment: Tecnicamente, o mail() me serve, mas, a questão é não chegar estes emails até o hotmail, por exemplo. @Bacco eu entendi a sua mensagem, mas, eu fiz um teste dentro do próprio arquivo if e else. if(mail($usuario, $senha, $email)) {echo "true";} logo... ele me retornou o TRUE. Isso me fez entender que a função está enviando... Certo?

Comment: true = enviado para a fila de saída. Da fila para o destino, só depende do sistema operacional, que vai fazer o envio propriamente dito. Se for *nix, geralmente é o `sendmail`. Olhando o log do _mailer_ pode ser que você encontre alguma dica (se foi entregue ou não, e qual a razão caso não tenha sido).

Comment: experimentei ele aqui no meu servidor e funciona. Porem essa linha está com erro `if($usuario_inserido) {sentRegister($usuario, $senha, $email);)` tem um parêntesis depois do ponto e virgula e tive que corrigir para `if($usuario_inserido) {sentRegister($usuario, $senha, $email);}`  substitui parêntesis por chave

Comment: Este é um exemplo @LeoCaracciolo. Obrigado por esta observação. :) Bacco, obrigado novamente. Irei verificar se meu servidor dispõe este recurso. :)